The Concurrency Issues of mod_timer and refcount_inc in the linux kernel
static int ip_frag_reinit(struct ipq *qp)
{
  unsigned int sum_truesize = 0;

  if (!mod_timer(&qp->q.timer, jiffies + qp->q.fqdir->timeout)) {
    refcount_inc(&qp->q.refcnt);
    return -ETIMEDOUT;
  }
}

There are many places in the kernel where this is written, but since ref_inc is after mod_timer,
The timer may have already been executed on another CPU when mod_timer returns.
is there a concurrency issue between mod_timer and ref_inc ?

"is there a concurrency issue between mod_timer and ref_inc?" - What kind of issue do you expect? refcount_inc is an atomic instruction, it is safe to call it from several threads at the same time.

refcount_inc is used to increase the reference count of an object. However, since the timer callback will access this object, the normal refcount_inc needs to be called before mod_timer.

The object is already referenced by the caller of ip_frag_reinit function (such precondition is common for all functions which use an object with the reference count). So it is safe to access this object even in other threads. Call of refcount_inc is used for create another reference to the object, which will exist even after the caller of ip_frag_reinit drop its reference.

void timer_callback()  {     refcount_dec(obj); }  The logic of the timer is like this, so I think we need to increase the reference count first every time we successfully add a timer.

Because even if the object is already referenced by the caller of ip_frag_reinit function, if the timer callback executes first, the object at the caller's side will face a UAF (Use After Free) issue.

The timer function is probably the ip_expire. It effectively calls refcount_dec_and_test at the end. But before that it acquires the lock. The function ip_frag_reinit is called with the lock taken, so it completes the refcount_inc before ip_expire reaches the end. I see no problem with that.

Thank you very much. I like it. You are right. I will analyze other places.
